# How to drag and open file in editor?

Tags: java, xml, swt, editor

I have a editor developed which opens the xml file and display it there (with the proper structure), for this I need to browse through all the times to select target file, in what way I can add dragging in file feature enable for this ?

The report editor is developed with Java SWT components.

I want to know the possible ways or API available for "dragging in" file ?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you.

`DragSource class` which provides the drag and drip API in SWT.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/DraggingandDropping.htm